# "Method not allowed" Graph API posting to batch endpoint

Tags: json, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have confirmed the JSON that is generated from inserting objects is correct, and I can pass this through the Graph Explorer without issues. When I try to run this Powershell script, I get the infamous `Method not allowed` error.

```
# CHANGE THESE VALUES
$TenantID = 'tenantid' #The Directory ID from Azure AD
$ClientID = 'clientid' #The Application ID of the registered app
$ClientSecret = 'secret' #The secret key of the registered app
# ------------------------------------------------------

# DO NOT CHANGE THESE
$body = @{grant_type="client_credentials";scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";client_id=$ClientID;client_secret=$ClientSecret}
$oauth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body
$requestHeaders = @{'Authorization'= "Bearer $($accesstoken)"; "Content-Type" = "application/json"}
# ------------------------------------------------------
 
$batchUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"
$myBatchRequests = @()
[int]$requestID = 0

$requestID ++
#E2
$myRequest = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{ 
    url = "/users?`$select=userprincipalname,displayname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber,employeeid,department,accountenabled,signInActivity&`$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId+eq+19ec0d23-8335-4cbd-94ac-6050e30712fa)"
    id = $requestID
    method = "GET"
} 
$myBatchRequests += $myRequest


$requestID ++
#E3
$myRequest = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{ 
    url = "/users?`$select=userprincipalname,displayname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber,employeeid,department,accountenabled,signInActivity&`$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId+eq+05e9a617-0261-4cee-bb44-138d3ef5d965)"
    id = $requestID
    method = "GET"
} 
$myBatchRequests += $myRequest

$requestID ++
#E5
$myRequest = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{ 
    url = "/users?`$select=userprincipalname,displayname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber,employeeid,department,accountenabled,signInActivity&`$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId+eq+06ebc4ee-1bb5-47dd-8120-11324bc54e06)"
    id = $requestID
    method = "GET"
} 
$myBatchRequests += $myRequest

$myBatchRequests

$allBatchRequests =  [pscustomobject][ordered]@{ 
    requests = $myBatchRequests
}

$batchBody = $allBatchRequests | ConvertTo-Json

$getBatchRequests = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $batchUrl -Body $batchBody -headers $requestHeaders
```

Error message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "Method not allowed",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-12-18T20:29:48",
      "request-id": "877741c0-3ad5-4481-80cf-d3756d589149",
      "client-request-id": "877741c0-3ad5-4481-80cf-d3756d589149"
    }
  }
}
```

I have confirmed that `$batchBody` appears as follows:

```
{
    "requests":  [
                     {
                         "url":  "/users?$select=userprincipalname,displayname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber,employeeid,department,accountenabled,signInActivity\u0026$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId+eq+19ec0d23-8335-4cbd-94ac-6050e30712fa)",
                         "id":  1,
                         "method":  "GET"
                     },
                     {
                         "url":  "/users?$select=userprincipalname,displayname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber,employeeid,department,accountenabled,signInActivity\u0026$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId+eq+05e9a617-0261-4cee-bb44-138d3ef5d965)",
                         "id":  2,
                         "method":  "GET"
                     },
                     {
                         "url":  "/users?$select=userprincipalname,displayname,extension_335d4df9847945fbaa472c8b8fbb5d75_employeeNumber,employeeid,department,accountenabled,signInActivity\u0026$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId+eq+06ebc4ee-1bb5-47dd-8120-11324bc54e06)",
                         "id":  3,
                         "method":  "GET"
                     }
                 ]
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to both make sure that this code posts to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch` properly, and also steps over the first 1000 results and returns the full list of results using `@odata.nextLink` ?

Comment: Perhaps the conversion from `&` to `\u0026` messes things up? What happens if you try `$batchBody = ($allBatchRequests | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '\\u0026', '&'`

Comment: Unfortunately, same error - UnknownError, Method  not allowed.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is mainly due to the below step.

```
$batchUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"
```

Replace this with $batchUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`$batch"

You are masking $ symbol in body requests but you are not doing it for main request and powershell searches for $batch variable if it is defined or not and the $batchurl will `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/` but not `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch`

Comment: I’ll try that thank you!! What’s the best way to incorporate ‘@odata.nextlink’?

Comment: You can create more batch requests with nextLinks and loop through that until the nextLink disappears. Give a try and if you face any issue please post a question in stackoverflow and community can help you.

Comment: I'm getting an error now `"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",`

Comment: That's because the access token is not properly passed $requestHeaders. Pull it properly like `$oauth."access_token"` and put it in headers. It will work.